# UISlider, save status

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, uislider

My question is about the `UISlider`. I managed to implement everything but i don't know how i can save its status.

Ive looked everywhere but al the posts are in older versions of swift/xcode. So the question is how do i save its status so that when i go to another view and then come back the status is still the same.

Thanks very much!

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

  var sequeInt = 0

  let savedWordLength = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var wordLength: UISlider!

  @IBOutlet weak var wordLengthValue: UILabel!

  var selectedValue: Int = 5

  @IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    selectedValue = Int(sender.value)

    savedWordLength.setInteger(selectedValue, forKey: "myInt")

    let ourInt = savedWordLength.integerForKey("myInt")
    sequeInt = ourInt
    print (sequeInt)

    wordLengthValue.text = String(ourInt)
}
```

Comment: First of all, think about what the "status" of a slider _is_. What does that word even _mean_? What information needs to be saved and restored. Then, read _any_ answer about saving and restoring info between instantiations of a view controller; this is trivially easy.

Answer (score 2):

UISlider value property is a Float so you can use NSUserDefault's method [setFloat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setFloat:forKey:) to save its value and retrieve it next time your view appears using NSUserDefaults method [floatForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/floatForKey:).

to save it:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(sender.value, forKey: "wordLength")
```

load it:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    wordLength.setValue(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("wordLength"), animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. In your view will appear.

   ```
   fontSlider.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "slider_value"), animated: false)
   ```
2. Take another outlet from storyBoard as "editingDidEnd".
   In that function:

   ```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(fontSlider.value, forKey: "slider_value")
   ```
3. And finally in your ValueChanged Outlet.

   ```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(fontSlider.value, forKey: "slider_value")
   ```